# pgadmin4 execute pgscript option not available

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I just switched from pgadmin3 to pgadmin4, just to check it out.

I was using the query tool and was not able to find execute as pgscript option at all, this was available in pgadmin3.

The documentation for pgadmin4 query tool does not mention anything about pgscript at all.

Is anyone else able to execute pgscripts in pgadmin4? 
Forgive me if I missed something, I spent over 3 hours searching for it and could not find it.

Comment: i've raised the same issue on [SE - Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/180330/execute-pgscript-in-pgadmin-4-while-skipping-errors/180413#180413) - doesn't look like it!

Comment: Do you mean execute any script using PGadmin like SQL or set cmds? Simply open the Query Tool by right click on the DB in PGadmin and execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to this thread in PgAdmin's webpage, you can't. It's became obsolete so they've removed this feature.
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BOCxozQ%3DO3HJn3eqd91ogWxQYszsrMYRmu%2Bhe_aWc0TUeV2nQ%40mail.gmail.com